# Determining if two expressions are equal, in order to ensure a Fourier series is correct

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

**Motivation:** I have a  question that asked me to find the Fourier series of some function $f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}A,\quad -1\lt x \leq 0 \\ Ax, \quad 0 \lt x \leq 1 \end{array}\right.$ periodic on $f(x+2)=f(x)$. They have given me what it is meant to equal in the end, so that we know if we have gone wrong.

---

**Question:** Is the below equality true? This is part of the Fourier series where my expression doesn't appear to simplify to their expression.

---

**Expressions:** Below is part of (Theirs = Mine)
$$2\frac{A}{\pi^2}\sum \limits_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2m+1^2)}\cos\left[(2m+1)\pi x\right]=-\frac{A}{\pi^2}\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} - \frac{1}{n^2} \cos(n\pi x)\right)$$

---

**Note:**

That $(2m+1^2)$ is exactly how it is written down in their expression, so I am not sure if the $1^2$ is a typo e.g. $(2m+1)^2$ or not.

---

Many thanks

Comment: put the square (of 1^2) outside of the bracket and I think it is correct. Also a (large) bracket is missing in your RHS.

Comment: @AndreasH. Thank you for your comment. Yes I did indeed forget that large bracket for the RHS, apologies. Are these equivalent because my $(-1)^n -1$ gives me a sequence of $-2,0-2,0,\dots$, and the series that have set up skips every second $n$ and is multiplied by this $-2$?

Comment: @AndreasH. Wait, I see my failure

Answer (score 1):

$$2\frac{A}{\pi^2}\sum \limits_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2m+1^2)}\cos\left[(2m+1)\pi x\right]\underset{\large\bf{=}}{?}-\frac{A}{\pi^2}\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} - \frac{1}{n^2} \cos(n\pi x)\right)$$

First note that the $(2m+1^2)$ should indeed be $(2m+1)^2$

Now we will note that $(-1)^n-1$ for $n=1,2,3,\dots$ is $-2,0,-2,0,\dots$ and we can take this $-2$ out the from the RHS, ensuring we are only counting for $n=1,3,5,\dots$ e.g. $n$ odd, giving:

$$\operatorname{RHS}=2\frac{A}{\pi^2}\sum \limits_{m=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(2m+1)^2}\cos((2m+1)\pi x)\right)=\operatorname{LHS}$$

Comment: well in principle this is "correct", but you are abusing notation. 1) You cant put an equals sign between two things which are not equal and 2) you cant say "almost giving:". This is an evil sin in mathematics :)

Comment: e.g. in your second equation, it would be correct to write $\sum_{n=1,3,5,...}$

Comment: @AndreasH. Oh that was more to mean, we are almost there, I didn't assume anything haha. But yes, I will delete the between step that is technically invalid.

Comment: in the first equation you could put an question mark above the equals sign, which could be read as "not-sure-if-equal" or "to-be-found-out-if-equal"

Comment: Oh I see, I am meant to start from $m=0$ so that $n=1$ is a valid computation, here moving back to $m=0$ would be giving me $n=1$ already

Comment: @AndreasH. Thank you for your help, it was appreciated!